# SQL Server 2019 unable to install error

Tags: sql-server, installation, errors

When installing SQL server 2019 receiving installation error.

**Error log**

```
  Overall summary:
  Final result:                  Failed: see details below
  Exit code (Decimal):           -2068052377
  Start time:                    2021-03-03 13:22:57
  End time:                      2021-03-03 13:23:28
  Requested action:              Install

Setup completed with required actions for features.
Troubleshooting information for those features:
  Next step for SQLEngine:       Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.


Machine Properties:
  Machine name:                  DESKTOP-MK92PRG
  Machine processor count:       12
  OS version:                    Microsoft Windows 10 Home (10.0.19041)
  OS service pack:               
  OS region:                     United States
  OS language:                   English (United States)
  OS architecture:               x64
  Process architecture:          64 Bit
  OS clustered:                  No

Product features discovered:
  Product              Instance             Instance ID                    Feature                                  Language             Edition              Version         Clustered  Configured

Package properties:
  Description:                   Microsoft SQL Server 2019 
  ProductName:                   SQL Server 2019
  Type:                          RTM
  Version:                       15
  SPLevel:                       0
  Installation location:         C:\SQL2019\Developer_ENU\x64\setup\
  Installation edition:          Developer

Product Update Status:
  User selected not to include product updates.

User Input Settings:
  ACTION:                        Install
  ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN:      false
  AGTSVCACCOUNT:                 NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT
  AGTSVCPASSWORD:                *****
  AGTSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Manual
  ASBACKUPDIR:                   Backup
  ASCOLLATION:                   Latin1_General_CI_AS
  ASCONFIGDIR:                   Config
  ASDATADIR:                     Data
  ASLOGDIR:                      Log
  ASPROVIDERMSOLAP:              1
  ASSERVERMODE:                  TABULAR
  ASSVCACCOUNT:                  <empty>
  ASSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  ASSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  ASSYSADMINACCOUNTS:            <empty>
  ASTELSVCACCT:                  <empty>
  ASTELSVCPASSWORD:              <empty>
  ASTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           0
  ASTEMPDIR:                     Temp
  BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE:         Disabled
  CLTCTLRNAME:                   <empty>
  CLTRESULTDIR:                  <empty>
  CLTSTARTUPTYPE:                0
  CLTSVCACCOUNT:                 <empty>
  CLTSVCPASSWORD:                <empty>
  CLTWORKINGDIR:                 <empty>
  COMMFABRICENCRYPTION:          0
  COMMFABRICNETWORKLEVEL:        0
  COMMFABRICPORT:                0
  CONFIGURATIONFILE:             C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20210303_132256\ConfigurationFile.ini
  CTLRSTARTUPTYPE:               0
  CTLRSVCACCOUNT:                <empty>
  CTLRSVCPASSWORD:               <empty>
  CTLRUSERS:                     <empty>
  ENABLERANU:                    false
  ENU:                           true
  EXTSVCACCOUNT:                 <empty>
  EXTSVCPASSWORD:                <empty>
  FEATURES:                      SQLENGINE
  FILESTREAMLEVEL:               0
  FILESTREAMSHARENAME:           <empty>
  FTSVCACCOUNT:                  <empty>
  FTSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  HELP:                          false
  IACCEPTPYTHONLICENSETERMS:     false
  IACCEPTROPENLICENSETERMS:      false
  IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS:  true
  IACKNOWLEDGEENTCALLIMITS:      false
  INDICATEPROGRESS:              true
  INSTALLSHAREDDIR:              C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTALLSHAREDWOWDIR:           C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTALLSQLDATADIR:             <empty>
  INSTANCEDIR:                   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server
  INSTANCEID:                    MSSQLSERVER
  INSTANCENAME:                  MSSQLSERVER
  ISMASTERSVCACCOUNT:            NT AUTHORITY\Network Service
  ISMASTERSVCPASSWORD:           <empty>
  ISMASTERSVCPORT:               8391
  ISMASTERSVCSSLCERTCN:          <empty>
  ISMASTERSVCSTARTUPTYPE:        Automatic
  ISMASTERSVCTHUMBPRINT:         <empty>
  ISSVCACCOUNT:                  NT AUTHORITY\Network Service
  ISSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  ISSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  ISTELSVCACCT:                  <empty>
  ISTELSVCPASSWORD:              <empty>
  ISTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           0
  ISWORKERSVCACCOUNT:            NT AUTHORITY\Network Service
  ISWORKERSVCCERT:               <empty>
  ISWORKERSVCMASTER:             <empty>
  ISWORKERSVCPASSWORD:           <empty>
  ISWORKERSVCSTARTUPTYPE:        Automatic
  MATRIXCMBRICKCOMMPORT:         0
  MATRIXCMSERVERNAME:            <empty>
  MATRIXNAME:                    <empty>
  MRCACHEDIRECTORY:              
  NPENABLED:                     0
  PBDMSSVCACCOUNT:               <empty>
  PBDMSSVCPASSWORD:              <empty>
  PBDMSSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           0
  PBENGSVCACCOUNT:               <empty>
  PBENGSVCPASSWORD:              <empty>
  PBENGSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           0
  PBPORTRANGE:                   <empty>
  PBSCALEOUT:                    false
  PID:                           *****
  QUIET:                         true
  QUIETSIMPLE:                   false
  ROLE:                          
  RSINSTALLMODE:                 DefaultNativeMode
  RSSVCACCOUNT:                  <empty>
  RSSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  RSSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  SAPWD:                         <empty>
  SECURITYMODE:                  <empty>
  SQLBACKUPDIR:                  <empty>
  SQLCOLLATION:                  SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
  SQLJAVADIR:                    <empty>
  SQLMAXDOP:                     12
  SQLMAXMEMORY:                  2147483647
  SQLMINMEMORY:                  0
  SQLSVCACCOUNT:                 NT Service\MSSQLSERVER
  SQLSVCINSTANTFILEINIT:         true
  SQLSVCPASSWORD:                <empty>
  SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Automatic
  SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS:           DESKTOP-MK92PRG\Munkh-Orgil
  SQLTELSVCACCT:                 NT Service\SQLTELEMETRY
  SQLTELSVCPASSWORD:             <empty>
  SQLTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE:          Automatic
  SQLTEMPDBDIR:                  <empty>
  SQLTEMPDBFILECOUNT:            8
  SQLTEMPDBFILEGROWTH:           64
  SQLTEMPDBFILESIZE:             8
  SQLTEMPDBLOGDIR:               <empty>
  SQLTEMPDBLOGFILEGROWTH:        64
  SQLTEMPDBLOGFILESIZE:          8
  SQLUSERDBDIR:                  <empty>
  SQLUSERDBLOGDIR:               <empty>
  SUPPRESSPAIDEDITIONNOTICE:     false
  SUPPRESSPRIVACYSTATEMENTNOTICE: false
  TCPENABLED:                    0
  UIMODE:                        Normal
  UpdateEnabled:                 false
  UpdateSource:                  MU
  USEMICROSOFTUPDATE:            false
  USESQLRECOMMENDEDMEMORYLIMITS: false
  X86:                           false

  Configuration file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20210303_132256\ConfigurationFile.ini

Detailed results:
  Feature:                       Database Engine Services
  Status:                        Failed
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred during the setup process of the feature.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
  Component name:                SQL Server Database Engine Services Instance Features
  Component error code:          1639
  Component log file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20210303_132256\sql_engine_core_inst_Cpu64_1.log
  Error description:             Invalid command line argument. Consult the Windows Installer SDK for detailed command line help.
  Error help link:               https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=15.0.4013.40&EvtType=sql_engine_core_inst.msi%400x162A16FE%400x1639

Rules with failures or warnings:

Global rules:
Warning    IsFirewallEnabled                The Windows Firewall is enabled. Make sure the appropriate ports are open to enable remote access. See the rules documentation at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2094702 for information about ports to open for each feature.

Rules report file:               C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20210303_132256\SystemConfigurationCheck_Report.htm
```

**Core components log**

```
=== Verbose logging started: 3/3/2021  13:23:20  Build type: SHIP UNICODE 5.00.10011.00  Calling process: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Setup Bootstrap\SQL2019\x64\ScenarioEngine.exe ===
MSI (c) (60:04) [13:23:20:287]: Resetting cached policy values
MSI (c) (60:04) [13:23:20:287]: Machine policy value 'Debug' is 0
MSI (c) (60:04) [13:23:20:287]: ******* RunEngine:
           ******* Product: C:\SQL2019\Developer_ENU\x64\setup\sql_engine_core_inst.msi
           ******* Action: 
           ******* CommandLine: **********
MSI (c) (60:04) [13:23:20:290]: Client-side and UI is none or basic: Running entire install on the server.
MSI (c) (60:04) [13:23:20:290]: Grabbed execution mutex.
MSI (c) (60:04) [13:23:20:294]: Cloaking enabled.
MSI (c) (60:04) [13:23:20:294]: Attempting to enable all disabled privileges before calling Install on Server
MSI (c) (60:04) [13:23:20:297]: Incrementing counter to disable shutdown. Counter after increment: 0
MSI (s) (C4:54) [13:23:20:301]: Running installation inside multi-package transaction C:\SQL2019\Developer_ENU\x64\setup\sql_engine_core_inst.msi
MSI (s) (C4:54) [13:23:20:301]: Grabbed execution mutex.
MSI (s) (C4:A0) [13:23:20:303]: Resetting cached policy values
MSI (s) (C4:A0) [13:23:20:303]: Machine policy value 'Debug' is 0
MSI (s) (C4:A0) [13:23:20:303]: ******* RunEngine:
           ******* Product: C:\SQL2019\Developer_ENU\x64\setup\sql_engine_core_inst.msi
           ******* Action: 
           ******* CommandLine: **********
MSI (s) (C4:A0) [13:23:20:304]: Machine policy value 'TransformsSecure' is 0
MSI (s) (C4:A0) [13:23:20:304]: User policy value 'TransformsAtSource' is 0
MSI (s) (C4:A0) [13:23:20:304]: Machine policy value 'DisableUserInstalls' is 0
MSI (s) (C4:A0) [13:23:20:304]: Specified instance {97E1B195-1A3F-4594-BC2B-BE2FD72AC74D} via transform :InstID02.mst;:InstName02.mst is already installed. MSINEWINSTANCE requires a new instance that is not installed.
MSI (s) (C4:A0) [13:23:20:304]: MainEngineThread is returning 1639
MSI (s) (C4:54) [13:23:20:306]: User policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (C4:54) [13:23:20:306]: Machine policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (C4:54) [13:23:20:306]: Incrementing counter to disable shutdown. Counter after increment: 0
MSI (s) (C4:54) [13:23:20:306]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback\Scripts 3: 2 
MSI (s) (C4:54) [13:23:20:306]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback\Scripts 3: 2 
MSI (s) (C4:54) [13:23:20:307]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
MSI (c) (60:04) [13:23:20:308]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
MSI (c) (60:04) [13:23:20:308]: MainEngineThread is returning 1639
=== Verbose logging stopped: 3/3/2021  13:23:20 ===
```

I have tried completely uninstalling SQL server by manually, even used Revo uninstall. Please help!

Comment: Sorry I missed that. Can you upload output of `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20210303_132256\sql_engine_core_inst_Cpu64_1.log` on shared drive and then post link here. The reason for failure would be mentioned in this file. I need to see the complete file.

Comment: Adding: I can see `Specified instance {97E1B195-1A3F-4594-BC2B-BE2FD72AC74D} via transform :InstID02.mst;:InstName02.mst is already installed. MSINEWINSTANCE requires a new instance that is not installed.` This is relevant message and may be the cause of your problem but just to be sure  I need to see complete logs. See if [this link](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2019/07/30/sql-server-2019-installation-failure-invalid-command-line-argument-consult-the-windows-installer-sdk-for-detailed-command-line-help/)helps